# C++ How to create an array of template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a classA which needs to hold an array of instances of classB.

```
class ClassA{
private:
  int size;
  ClassB *array;
public:
  ClassA(int size){
    array= new ClassB[size];
  }
  template <typename ValueType>
  void Add(int key, ValueType& value);
};

class ClassB{
  int key;
  ??? value;
}
```

The obstacle is that I need a member value of classB to be any type. Because I'm planning to pass reference of any data type using function Add().

My first clue was to use template class, like this

```
template<Class T>
class ClassB{
  int key;
  T value;
}
```

But in this case compiler doesn't let me to create an array array= new ClassB[size], probably because I need to specify type before creating an array.

Shortly, I need an array to be like this:

array[0] = instance of ClassB {int key, int& value}

array[1] = instance of ClassB {int key, double& value}

array[2] = instance of ClassB {int key, std::string& value}

How can I create an array of class instances with different data type? If it's not possible how can I achieve storing reference of different data types in one array?

I can't use std::pair<> or any other STL containers.

Thank you!

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384739/c-map-with-different-data-types-as-values). Most people that run into this problem end up using [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html) if they can.

Comment: @CoryKramer Thank you, but I need to do it using standart tools. Is it even possbile?

Comment: Yes it is possible without Boost, see the duplicate link. It is a bit more cumbersome, but you can do something like that. Specifically I am referring to the answer by [@Useless](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14143094/2296458)

Comment: @CoryKramer Thank you so much, it helps a lot. Looks like I need to implement discriminated union, correct me If I'm wrong :)

Comment: @CoryKramer can you please give me an expample how can I do it using union? An exmaple by link each data type needs to be predifined. But for my problem I might need to store reference to an instance of custom class.